# im trying to get snapshot data and assign it to a label I made but I get error Cannot assign value of type '[String : Any]' to type 'String'

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to get snapshot data and assign it to a label I made but I get error Cannot assign value of type '[String : Any]' to type 'String'
its most likely me and just bad code im trying  any advice or help would be highly appreciated

```
    func loadUserName(){

    if(AccessToken.current != nil){
        //perform code FOR FACEBOOK YOUR GOING TO HAVE TO GRAB IT FROM FIREBASE

        FirebaseReferece(.User).document(AccessToken.current!.userID).collection("first_name").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if (error != nil) {

                print("error getting username description is \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            } else {

                for allDocument in snapshot!.documents {

                    let currentUsername = allDocument.data()

                    self.usernameTextLabel.text! = currentUsername



                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: can you post a photo or show in code how does your user model is structured in firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API documentation, [data()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot#data) with no arguments returns an NSDictionary containing all of the fields in the document, indexed by the field name.  That's obviously not a string, and you can't use it as such to populate your view.

Maybe what you want instead is to use [get(x)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot#get_:) and pass the name of the field (which we don't know for sure.  Or maybe index into the dictionary to find what you need:

```
let data = allDocument.data()
let value = data["name_of_the_field"]
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the response you get from firebase comes like a `[String: Any]` dictionary; `String` being the key to your object attribute. So in your case if you want to retrieve the "first_name" of your user, you would write something like this:

```
self.usernameTextLabel.text! = currentUsername["first_name"]
```